# Touchpad works when system starts then after some time click stop working?

Tags: touchpad

I have Hp 1000 laptop. Touchpad works when system starts then after some time click stop working? I was wondering if anyone else encountered the same situation. I am using synthetic keypad driver.

Comment: What OS you are using?

Comment: windows 8,. i have reinstalled the new window as well but still difference,.,

Comment: one thing if it helps is i installed and used Team viewer then system hung up and suddenly my keypad started to do this behaviour